# Qual é a finalidade do simbolo :: no Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, java-8

Implementei um método que soma todos o números de uma lista do tipo `List<Integer>` da seguinte forma:

```
int soma = 0;

for (Integer num : numeros)
    soma += num;
return soma;
```

Porém, a IDE NetBeans sugeriu para que eu substitui-se a rotina acima pela seguinte rotina abaixo:

```
int soma = 0;
return numeros.stream().map((numero) -> numero).reduce(soma, Integer::sum);
```

Sei que a rotina acima utiliza novas características do Java 8, contudo, fiquei em duvida a respeito do simbolo **`::`** usado no método `reduce()`, não sei se é algum tipo de operador, eu gostaria de saber qual é a sua finalidade?

Comment: Até que consegui entender a chamada em lambda, só não sei te explicar, senão respondia :/

Comment: @DiegoF se quiser, pode complementar minha resposta. Eu estou pelo celular agora e não vou conseguir melhorá-la. Até porque eu desconheço o método `reduce`.

Comment: @jbueno é um método da classe Stream, que por sinal ainda é obscura pra mim, já que é recente.

Comment: Aparentemente é uma boa explicação do uso, se meu inglês fosse bom, eu até resumiria o conteudo: http://netjs.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/method-reference-in-java-8.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

O operador `::` foi adicionado ao Java 8 e faz parte de expressões que referenciam métodos [(*Method Reference Expressions*)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13).

As referências a métodos ([*Method References*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)) funcionam como complemento aos lambdas.

Um lambda é como um trecho de código que você pode passar como argumento para um método. Só que às vezes esse trecho de código se repete ou já está implementado em algum método, portanto, você pode simplesmente referenciar um método qualquer.

Segundo a documentação, existem basicamente quatro tipo de referências a métodos:

## 1. Método estático

```
public static void medirTempo(Runnable rotinaDemorada, Supplier<Long> timestampSupplier) {
    long inicio = timestampSupplier.get();
    rotinaDemorada.run();
    System.out.format("Tempo: %d ms", timestampSupplier.get() - inicio);
}
```

`Runnable` é uma interface funcional que abstrai uma tarefa a ser executada. Ela não recebe nem retorna valor. `Supplier` é uma interface funcional cuja execução retorna um valor de um certo tipo, `Long` neste caso.

Dada uma rotina que demora:

```
Runnable rotinaDemorada = () -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
};
```

Podemos chamar o método assim:

```
medirTempo(rotinaDemorada, System::currentTimeMillis);
```

Coloquei o lambda numa variável separada para fins didáticos, mas poderíamos passar ele diretamente como parâmetro.

Assim, passamos um lambda e depois o método estático `currentTimeMillis` da classe `System` como argumentos. Quando a rotina de medição executa, `timestampSupplier.get()` é exatamente o mesmo que `System.currentTimeMillis()`. O método estático é chamado duas vezes, no início e no fim, onde a diferença de tempo é então impressa no console.

Note que `System.currentTimeMillis()` não recebe parâmetros e retorna um número longo, portanto é compatível com a interface funcional. O mesmo serve para o lambda que é atribuído para a variável `Runnable`, isto é, ele não tem parâmetros e não retorna valor.

## 2. Método de uma instância específica

Exemplo:

```
public int tamanho(Supplier<Integer> s) {
    return s.get();
}
```

`Supplier` é uma interface funcional cuja execução retorna um valor de um certo tipo, `Integer` neste caso.

Podemos chamar o método assim:

```
String s = "Hello, Instance Method!";
int t = tamanho(s::length);
```

Aqui passamos o método `length` do objeto `s` como argumento. Quando a rotina executa, `s.get()` é exatamente o mesmo que `s.length()`. O tamanho da `String` é retornada.

Note que `s.length()` não recebe parâmetros e retorna um inteiro, portanto é compatível com a interface funcional.

Outro ponto interessante é que você poderia passar `List.size ()` para a rotina com a interface funcional. Portanto, o mecanismo de compatibilidade de interfaces permite um outro nível de programação genérica.

## 3. Método de uma classe aplicado a qualquer instância

Exemplo:

```
public int tamanho(Function<String, Integer> f) {
    return f.apply("Hello, Class Method!");
}
```

`Function` é uma interface funcional que recebe um valor do tipo `T` (`String`) e retorna um valor do tipo `R` (`Integer`).

Podemos chamar o método assim:

```
int t = tamanho(String::length);
```

Aqui passamos o método `length` da classe `String` como argumento. Quando a rotina executa, `f.apply("...")` é exatamente o mesmo que chamar o método `"...".length()`, ou seja, na `String` passada como argumento para `apply`.

Note que no exemplo anterior, a interface funcional não sabe a qual objeto o método pertence. Neste exemplo, podemos chamar o método em qualquer instância do tipo.

## 4. Referência a um construtor

Exemplo:

```
public String newHello(Function<String, String> f) {
    return f.apply("Hello, Constructor!");
}
```

`Function` é uma interface funcional que recebe um valor do tipo `T` (`String`) e retorna um valor do tipo `R` (também `String`).

Podemos chamar o método assim:

```
String s = newHello(String::new);
```

Aqui passamos o construtor `String(String)` como argumento. Quando a rotina executa, `f.apply("...")` é exatamente o mesmo que instanciar a String assim: `new String("...")`.

Na prática, não existe muita diferença entre esta abordagem e a anterior, exceto que usar construtores facilita a utilização de objetos imutáveis como `String`, `BigDecimal`, `Integer` e outros ao usar a API funcional.

## Sobre a transformação do NetBeans

O código gerado pela IDE não é bom:

```
int soma = 0;
return numeros.stream().map((numero) -> numero).reduce(soma, Integer::sum);
```

### Mapeamento desnecessário

Não sei porque a IDE gerou uma chamada ao método `map`. Ele serve basicamente quando você quer transformar todos os valores de um *stream* em alguma outra coisa, gerando um novo *stream*. Neste caso é totalmente desnecessário.

O código abaixo gera o mesmo resultado:

```
int soma = 0;
return numeros.stream().reduce(soma, Integer::sum);
```

### Variável desnecessária

A variável `soma` não é necessária, já que define apenas um valor inicial.

O código abaixo gera o mesmo resultado:

```
return numeros.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

### Alternativa: `IntStream.sum()`

A API de *Streams* do Java 8 possibilita executar uma determinada operação numa sequência de valores e agregar o resultado de alguma forma. Isto é análogo às operações de agregação do SQL como `SUM` e `AVG`.

Um dos exemplos é o método [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce) que possui os parâmetros:

1. Valor inicial
2. Método de agregação

Entretanto, existem atalhos para as operações comuns em números tais como na classe `IntStream` que implementa [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--), `min`, `max`, `average` e `count`.

Na documentação de `sum`, lê-se que que ela é equivalente a `reduce(0, Integer::sum)`. Portanto, poderíamos reescrever o código assim:

```
return numeros.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

### Alternativa: array de primitivos

O `matpToInt` no exemplo anterior apmente é necessário porque o *stream* inicial não era do tipo `IntStream`.

Isso não seria necessário se ao invés de `List<Integer>` você tivesse um array primitivo `int[]`.

Exemplo:

```
int[] numerosArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Então o código para usar o `sum` seria apenas:

```
return IntStream.of(numerosArray).sum();
```

Comment: Eu estava esperando uma resposta sua *=)*

Comment: Só por curiosidade, por que `Supplier<Integer>` no lugar de `IntSupplier`?

Answer (score 5):

É uma nova característica da linguagem na versão 8. Chamasse *Method Reference* ou *Referência de Método*. O recurso fornece uma maneira de referenciarmos um método sem executá-lo. Além disso, está relacionado às expressões lambda porque, como elas, requer um contexto de tipo de destino composto por uma interface funcional compatível. Quando um *Method Reference* é avaliado, uma instância de uma interface funcional é criada. Essa definição bonita tirei do livro do [Schildt](http://www.mhprofessional.com/details.php?isbn=0071809252)

Um exemplo:

```
@Test
public void remove_null_from_list_java8_lambda () {
    List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList(null, "www", null, "leveluplunch", "com", null);

    List<String> filterStrings = strings
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertEquals(3, filterStrings.size());

    // or
    List<String> filterStrings2 = strings
        .stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertEquals(3, filterStrings2.size());
}
```

A linha `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` está chamando o método [Objects.nonNull(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) passando como parâmetro um objeto (o atual) da lista. Ou seja, declarou o método sem invocá-lo explicitamente.

O exemplo eu tirei [daqui](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/remove-filter-null-references-from-collection-list/).

Mais informações no [Tutorial java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (em inglês).

Comment: Se eu lembrar algum exemplo melhor/mais didático eu atualizo a resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Esse operador é chamado de [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Em poucas palavras ele serve para referenciar o método `sum` da classe `Integer`. Neste caso, você está passando o método `sum` como segundo parâmetro do `reduce`.